# Запретить создание экземпляра класса. Создание фабрики C++

Tags: c++, абстрактная-фабрика

Пишу для себя гуишку. Есть главный `class GUI` который занимается управлением всеми элементами (`class Widget`), создание этих элементов должно происходить только через этот `GUI`, для регистрации.

Думал что-то вроде такого:

1) Абстрактный класс виджетов:

```
class Widget {
public:
    /* ... */
    virtual ~Widget();

protected:
    friend class GUI;

    Widget();

    /* ... */
private:

};
```

2) Класс GUI:

```
class GUI {
public:
    /* ... */

    template<class WidgetType>
    WidgetType* create(AbstractContainer* parent = nullptr) {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Widget, WidgetType>::value, "Error...");

        std::shared_ptr<Widget> widget = std::make_shared<WidgetType>();
        widget->m_id = m_currentWidgetID;
        m_currentWidgetID++;

        WidgetType* result = reinterpret_cast<WidgetType*>(widget.get());

        if (parent != nullptr) {
            m_centralWidget->addWidget(widget);
        }
        else {
            parent->addWidget(widget);
        }

        return result;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractContainer> m_centralWidget;

    /* ... */
};
```

Сама проблема в спецификации `friend class GUI`, которая не распространяется на классы наследники, из чего следует, что мне надо писать для каждого наследника `friend class GUI`. Это необходимо, т.к. конструкторы спрятаны в `protected`, чтобы можно было запретить создание экземпляра класса виджета напрямую `Widget()`, сделав это только через фабрику `GUI::create()`.

Без `friend class GUI` я не знаю как дать доступ к `protected` зоне класса элемента, где лежит конструктор.

**Сам вопрос:**
Как выйти из ситуации и сделать правильно эту фабрику?

Answer (score 2):

Тут классический случай. Ваш класс `GUI` реализован так, что знает об имплементации класс `Widget`, если вы хотите чтоб наследники тоже могли получить прямой доступ до `Widget`, то надо выделить приватныу часть интерфейса и публичную. (*Это очень странное решение, разрешать всем наследникам лезть в имплементацию `Widget`, обычно таких классов должно быть ограниченное количество и все они тесно связаны с имплементаций `Widget`*)

```
// WidgetPrivate.h
namespace details
{
class WidgetPrivate
{
public:
    virtual void privateMethod1() = 0;
    virtual int& accessToPrivateInt() = 0;
    ...
};
}

// Widget.h

class Widget : protected details::WidgetPrivate
{
    friend class GUI;
public:
    void somePublicMethod();
    int getInt();
    //...
protected:
    WidgetPrivate& privateInterface(); // <- никто, кроме GUI и наследников не дотянется до этого метода

    void privateMethod1() override;
    int& accessToPrivateInt() override;

};

// Widget.cpp
WidgetPrivate& Widget::privateInterface()
{
    return *this;
}
```

Теперь, те кто должен иметь доступ к потрохам `Widget` используют метод `privateInterface`, такие включения и точки использования очень легко искать по `grep privateInterface *`

```
class GUI
{
protected:
    static WidgetPrivate& widgetPrivateInterface(Widget& w) {
        return w->privateInterface();
    }
}

class GUIDrived : public GUI
{
     void x() {
         widgetPrivateInterface(*widget).accessToPrivateInt() = 5;
     }
private:
    Widget * widget;

}
```

То все наследники будут иметь доступ до приватного интерфейса.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я не особо понял, как это должно решать проблему построения фабрики? У меня проблема именно в том, что `GUI` должен знать о конструкторе виджета, который **должен быть** в `protected`. То есть я хочу на уровне написания кода запретить создавать экземпляры класса, помещая конструкторы в скрытую часть, и делать это только через мастер функцию `GUI::create()`, которая уже вернет управляемый объект. Именно для этого я использовал `friend class GUI`

Answer (score 1):

У меня была примерно такая же проблема года 2 назад. Единственное (но не самое лучшее) решение, которое я нашел, заключалось в том, что бы в конструктор, в нашем случае, класса Widget, передавать параметр-пустышку какого нибудь другого класса, у которого в друзьях будет класс GUI. Таким образом, что бы создать экземпляр класса Widget, нужно будет создать экземпляр класса-пустышки. А это можно будет сделать только из фабрики.
Вот примерная реализация:

```
class GUI;

class Stub
{
    Stub() {}
    friend GUI;
};

class Widget 
{
public:
    /* ... */
    virtual ~Widget();

protected:
    friend class GUI;

    Widget(Stub st);

    /* ... */
private:

};

class SomeRealWidget: public Widget
{
public:
    SomeRealWidget(Stub st): Widget(st)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
};

class GUI {
public:
    /* ... */

    template<class WidgetType>
    WidgetType* create(AbstractContainer* parent = nullptr) {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Widget, WidgetType>::value, "Error...");
        Stub st;
        std::shared_ptr<Widget> widget = std::make_shared<WidgetType>(st);
        widget->m_id = m_currentWidgetID;
        m_currentWidgetID++;

        WidgetType* result = reinterpret_cast<WidgetType*>(widget.get());

        if (parent != nullptr) {
            m_centralWidget->addWidget(widget);
        }
        else {
            parent->addWidget(widget);
        }

        return result;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractContainer> m_centralWidget;

    /* ... */
};
```

К сожалению, другого варианта я не нашел. Будет здорово, если в класса Stub у вас получится впихнуть что-нибудь общее для всех виджетов, что нужно будет для их инициализации, тогда такой вариант будет почти оправдан.

Comment: К сожалению это ничем не лучше, чем писать у каждого нового класса `friend class GUI`, только в этом варианте еще и будет тратиться время на создание лишнего объекта.

Comment: Ну тут хотя бы не нужно заботиться о том, что в каждом наследнике нужно будет добавлять друга. На мой взгляд, это облегчает поддержку и дальнейшее развитие кода. По поводу время на создание объекта, то можно попробовать сделать его статическим в классе GUI и всегда использовать один экземпляр (хотя я не уверен в этом утверждении). К сожалению, других вариантов решения проблемы я не нашел.

Comment: Если передавать const Stub&, то хватит одного глобального объекта, доступного GUI. Оверхеда нет. Хотя, компиляторы умные, и в вашем случае оверхеда тоже нет.